# Consequences + of + to / for

Tags: prepositions, to-for

While learning some new words recently, I've come across the word **"consequence"** which has caused me some trouble. I understand the meaning of the word but linking it with other words is a bit problematic.

1. I`m not sure if it could be followed by "of"

> Negative consequences **of** fast-developing tourism...

2. I don`t know if it should be followed by "for" or "to"

> Negative consequences of fast-developing toursim **for/to** the enviroment and local societies

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. Negative consequences of tourism are things that happen as a result of tourism, they are caused by tourism: overpriced restaurants, crowded beaches, pollution...
2. for : "negative consequences for..."  would indicate who is harmed or inconvenienced by the tourism: the locals, the environment

I can't think of any time I would use "consequences to"

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sarah. Do you think it's gramatically and/or stylistically correct to use "Consequences" with both "OF" and "FOR" in one sentence? Like in the example I gave: "Negative consequences of fast-developing toursim for the enviroment and local societies" ? It sounds a little off to my ear but I can`t tell why

Comment: It is fine to use both. There are some examples on Linguee that use both http://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=consequences+of

Comment: I think you can also say *consequences **on** the environment*.

Comment: @Barmar *consequences on the environment* sounds very weird to this native speaker. To make it work it needs a specific context like a particular verb taking the position *on,* such as *the teacher imposed several negative consequences on the students.* But that's still rather odd.

Comment: In "Negative consequences of fast-developing toursim for the enviroment and local societies", it's *consequences of* and *tourism for*. So, *consequences* is **not** being used with *for*.